# How can I extract the HTML inside all the script tags that appear before a certain pattern in a web page?

Tags: c#

I have a variable inside a script tag in a web page. I want to use the HTML Agility Pack to extract content (e.g. all the css code) that appears before this variable is initialized. I'm able to extract all the style tags on the page using the following code.

```
string source = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(source);
HtmlNode[] styleNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//style").ToArray();
```

Is there a way I can extract the style tags appearing before and after the variable separately?

Comment: Have you tried to use `NextSibling` and `PreviousSibling` methods of the `HtmlNode` class to get the next and the previous elements correspondingly?

Comment: How the HTML looks like?

Comment: It's like the following: <style>......</style><script type="text/javascript">.....</script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[dummy = 5;//]]></script>   I want to get all the <script nodes before the variable 'dummy'.

Comment: Iterate NextSibling until InnerText contains [CDATA[dummy = 5;//].